# Checking Schedule for Crawl with a Business Essentials license?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, crawl, schedule

My organization has a **Business Essential** license for SharePoint Online.  Where would we go to review the configuration for the Crawl Schedule?

If it isn't configurable, what is the default crawl schedule for that kind of license?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant check that. In office 365 Continuous crawls are enabled , with crawl frequencies managed by Microsoft.

> Search crawls occur continuously to make sure that content changes are
>   available through search results as soon as possible. Recently
>   uploaded documents may not immediately be displayed in search results
>   because of the time that's required to process them. SharePoint Online
>   targets between 15 minutes and an hour for the time between upload and
>   availability in search results (also known as index freshness). In
>   cases of heavy environment use, this time can increase to six hours.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2008449